# Stop a do loop with a command button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA excel userform that is misbehaving. Basically I want my code to pause until a command button on a userform is pressed. Any ideas?

In a module:

```
Public okayclicked as boolean

Sub MyThing
  UserForm1.Show
  Do Until okayclicked
     DoEvents
  Loop
 UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

In my userform:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   okayclicked = True
End Sub
```

Not sure what else to try to make this work. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Or, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/showmodal-property (which, aside from its being much simpler, should keep the form from eating up a big chunk of CPU while it's showing, unlike your busy-wait).

Comment: Your question's title says you want to Stop the loop with button, but your question says you want your code paused until it's pressed. So which is it?

Comment: That `DoEvents` loop is a disaster waiting to happen. You need to change the whole paradigm and go event-driven. Look into `Event` and `WithEvents` keywords.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I want the code paused.

Comment: I know. And you can't - not with this procedural top-to-bottom paradigm.

Comment: Right now it's not clear what you're trying to achieve and why. X-Y questions are hard to answer, because you have problem Y and you're asking about X. Please [edit] your question to clarify. See [ask] and [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a `MsgBox` to ask for the user input, or set your form to be `Modal` ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/showmodal-property)).

A Modal form will allow you to continue to work in the form, and any code underlying the form will continue to run, but the main code that calls the form will be 'blocked'.

Should the underlying Excel sheets be modified during the period of pause, you can add code when the button press is detected (i.e. when the Form is closed or then the MsgBox `OK` button is pressed) to update the relevant parts of the Form.

But  we have digressed from the original simple question and many other factors (such as how the underlying sheets will be modified when the form is open) come into play.

- Consider if a change in the underlying sheet has to change the form immediately or if it can occur when the user resumes the form/code.
- Consider if the functions you want can be done natively in the spreadsheet and minimise the use/functionality of the form.
- Consider other event driven options where the code is broken into natural sections, functions, subroutines or modules and each section only runs when triggered by the right event (sheet change, user input, subroutine finished, form exit etc.)

Comment: I need the userform to be updated constantly because it is a timer. So I think I need modeless for that? Can I change modality as I please?

Comment: @HunterB: Updated the answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Tried setting up the page as    UserForm1.Show vbModal    but that did not do the trick. The page updates which I execute aside from the shown code do not update the userform properly

Comment: FWIW `UserForm1.Show` and `UserForm1.Show vbModal` both do exactly the same thing: display the *default instance* modally (`vbModal` is the default.... as explained in that MSDN link).

Comment: Why the down vote? The above two methods will pause the code until either the MsgBox button is pressed or the Form is closed. I know it is a short answer, but it is simple in its completeness.

Comment: @HunterB: This "page updates" is a new aspect in your question. This changes the answer slightly. Perhaps fully explaining what you want rather than drip feeding at every answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
'module
Sub MyThing1
   UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Public Sub MyThing2
    '....rest of code
End Sub

'userform
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   MyThing2
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is fairly old, but I found this thread through a search and the above helped me greatly!